# How to write constraints for hasMany properties in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have three classes in grails application

```
class Category {
    String name
}

class Application {
    String name
    static hasMany =[specialCategoryies:SpecialCategory]
}

class SpecialCategory {
    Category category
    Integer points
    static belongsTo =[application:Application]
}
```

Here while I am saving the applicationInstance I don't want save duplicate 
specialCategories values like ..specialCategories does not have same
category value again ..

```
application.addToSpecialCategoryies(newSpecialCategory(category:Category.get(1),points:2))
application.addToSpecialCategoryies(newSpecialCategory(category:Category.get(1),points:3))
```

here i application instance should rise error that category value repeated..
    so how define constraints for hasMany properties in domain class......?
    suggest how to write constraints to avoid duplicate values of category

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use hasMany out of the box for this.  Probably the best solution is defining your own relationship linking domain type and enforcing the rules with a "unique" constraint there.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a custom validator in your Application constraints section. For example, one way to check for duplicate property values is to collect the values into an array and compare them to the corresponding *unique* array (with duplicated elements removed):

```
class Application {

    String name
    static hasMany =[specialCategoryies:SpecialCategory]

    static constraints = {
        specialCategoryies validator: { specialCategories, obj ->

            def specialCategoriesIdArray =  specialCategories.collect {it?.category?.getId()}
            return (specialCategoriesIdArray.size() == specialCategoriesIdArray.unique().size())?true:'application.validator.specialcategoryduplicate.error'

        }
    }
}
```

When trying to save a special category with an existing category, it will throw a validation error when saving. You can test with the following:

```
    def cat1 = new Category(name:"Cat 1").save(flush:true)
    def cat2 = new Category(name:"Cat 2").save(flush:true)

    def app = new Application()
    app.name = "Test"

    app.addToSpecialCategoryies(new SpecialCategory(category: Category.get(1), points:2))
    app.addToSpecialCategoryies(new SpecialCategory(category: Category.get(2), points:2))
    app.addToSpecialCategoryies(new SpecialCategory(category: Category.get(1), points:3))

   if ( app.save(flush:true)   ){
          log.info "Saved!"
   }   else {
          log.error "NOT Saved. Error:"
       app.errors.each {
           log.error it
       }
   }
```